# How does integral term in PID lead to reduced stability margin?

Tags: control, pid-controller

Please can someone explain the following statement related to integral term. I read this in a reputed journal paper "From PID to Active Disturbance Rejection Control" by Jingqing Han:

> The integral term (in PID controller), while critical to rid of steady-state error, introduces other problems such as reduced stability margin due to phase lag

How does it lead to reduced stability margin?

Comment: Look up "Loop Stability" and then ask about points you may be unclear about.

Comment: Regarding the "reputed journal paper" which you quoted: Please can you edit the question and add a link to that paper (if it's available online) or a full reference (title, author(s), date etc.) so that people here can read the full paper, if they want to read it. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson  Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integrator adds 90° of phase lag at all frequencies. This has a detrimental effect on phase margin. For example, add an integrator to a first order system and you turn a well behaved 1st order exponential step response into a 2nd order, potentially oscillatory response.